# How can I use my classes in several projects?

Tags: .net, vb.net, class-library

How can I create a namespace and classes in it, then save it, and reuse the namespace in other projects? Do I have to click on Create Class Library in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in [Understanding and Using Assemblies and Namespaces in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973231.aspx)

**Here's what you need to do:**

1. Create a Class Library
2. Build it to generate a .dll file
3. And add a reference to the dll file 
           in any project to use it

Comment: @Codbold: Is there any guide or tutorial to do this?

Comment: @AkramShahda: I was reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973231.aspx but about referencing I figured it out by myself.

Answer (score 2):

Sort of .. To create types and use them in several projects you need to place them in a seperate assembly. This assembly could be generated from a class library, or any other project type. The type of the assembly file could be either a *dynamic library* or an *executable*.

You can place those types in a specific `namespace`. Also, you can place them in several *namespaces*.

To use these types from an external project you have to do the following:

1. Add a reference to the mentioned assembly.
2. Either importing the namespaces that contains those classes in your code file. Or, using their fully qualified names.

---

Refer to [Implementing a Class Library in VB.NET](http://www.csunit.org/tutorials/tutorial6/)

Comment: Is there any guide or tutorial to do this?

Comment: I know how to create classes and namespaces, but I don't know how to reuse them in other projects.